# Passing data from node.js to react using express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm trying to call an API(which only allows server side calls) in nodejs. I manage to get the info back to my console, and now Im trying to pass that data to the app.js file of my react app.

Im currently working with a react app a node.js back end and express to communicate between them.

I have two folder `backend` and `client`

This is `backend/server.js`:

```
const express = require("express");
const API_PORT = 3001;
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

  router.get("/bitmex", () => !async function(){
      const api = new BitmexAPI({
        "apiKeyID": "",
        "apiKeySecret": ""
      });
       const chatMessage = await api.Position.get()
       return(chatMessage.json({ success: true, chatMessage}))
  }())

  app.listen(API_PORT, () => console.log(`LISTENING ON PORT ${API_PORT}`));
```

And this is `client/App.js`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";


 class App extends Component {
 // initialize our state 
 state = {
    data: [],
 };



 // when component mounts, first thing it does is fetch all existing 
 data in our db
 // then we incorporate a polling logic so that we can easily see if our db has 
 // changed and implement those changes into our UI
 componentDidMount() {
 console.log("this worked successfully")
 this.getDataFromDb();
 }

 getDataFromDb = () => {
     fetch("http://localhost:3001/bitmex")
     .then(data => chatMessage.json())
     .then(res => this.setState({ data: res.data }));
 };




// here is our UI
// it is easy to understand their functions when you 
// see them render into our screen
render() {
const { data } = this.state;
return (
  <div>
    <ul>
      //render data here somehow
    </ul>
  </div>
);
}
}

export default App;
```

The response from the API looks like this:

> ```
> [
>    {
>     "account": 0,
>     "symbol": "string",
>     "currency": "string",
>     "underlying": "string",
>     "quoteCurrency": "string",
>     "commission": 0,
>     "initMarginReq": 0,
>     "maintMarginReq": 0,
>     "riskLimit": 0,
>     "leverage": 0,
>     "crossMargin": true,
>     "deleveragePercentile": 0,
>     "rebalancedPnl": 0,
>     "prevRealisedPnl": 0,
>     "prevUnrealisedPnl": 0,
>     "prevClosePrice": 0,
>     "openingTimestamp": "2019-02-13T18:37:44.780Z",
>     "openingQty": 0,
>     "openingCost": 0,
>     "openingComm": 0,
>     "openOrderBuyQty": 0,
>     "openOrderBuyCost": 0,
>     "openOrderBuyPremium": 0,
>     "openOrderSellQty": 0,
>     "openOrderSellCost": 0,
>     "openOrderSellPremium": 0,
>     "execBuyQty": 0,
>     "execBuyCost": 0,
>     "execSellQty": 0,
>     "execSellCost": 0,
>     "execQty": 0,
>     "execCost": 0,
>     "execComm": 0,
>     "currentTimestamp": "2019-02-13T18:37:44.780Z",
>     "currentQty": 0,
>     "currentCost": 0,
>     "currentComm": 0,
>     "realisedCost": 0,
>     "unrealisedCost": 0,
>     "grossOpenCost": 0,
>     "grossOpenPremium": 0,
>     "grossExecCost": 0,
>     "isOpen": true,
>     "markPrice": 0,
>     "markValue": 0,
>     "riskValue": 0,
>     "homeNotional": 0,
>     "foreignNotional": 0,
>     "posState": "string",
>     "posCost": 0,
>     "posCost2": 0,
>     "posCross": 0,
>     "posInit": 0,
>     "posComm": 0,
>     "posLoss": 0,
>     "posMargin": 0,
>     "posMaint": 0,
>     "posAllowance": 0,
>     "taxableMargin": 0,
>     "initMargin": 0,
>     "maintMargin": 0,
>     "sessionMargin": 0,
>     "targetExcessMargin": 0,
>     "varMargin": 0,
>     "realisedGrossPnl": 0,
>     "realisedTax": 0,
>     "realisedPnl": 0,
>     "unrealisedGrossPnl": 0,
>     "longBankrupt": 0,
>     "shortBankrupt": 0,
>     "taxBase": 0,
>     "indicativeTaxRate": 0,
>     "indicativeTax": 0,
>     "unrealisedTax": 0,
>     "unrealisedPnl": 0,
>     "unrealisedPnlPcnt": 0,
>     "unrealisedRoePcnt": 0,
>     "simpleQty": 0,
>     "simpleCost": 0,
>     "simpleValue": 0,
>     "simplePnl": 0,
>     "simplePnlPcnt": 0,
>     "avgCostPrice": 0,
>     "avgEntryPrice": 0,
>     "breakEvenPrice": 0,
>     "marginCallPrice": 0,
>     "liquidationPrice": 0,
>     "bankruptPrice": 0,
>     "timestamp": "2019-02-13T18:37:44.781Z",
>     "lastPrice": 0,
>     "lastValue": 0
>   }
> ]
> ```

I m looking to get the info returned by the API rendered in the react app.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the backend script to include body parser

```js
// backend/server.js
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
// Set up the express app
const app = express();
const API_PORT = 3001;
// Parse incoming requests data
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));


app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
 next();
});

app.get("/bitmex", () => !async function(){
      const api = new BitmexAPI({
        "apiKeyID": "",
        "apiKeySecret": ""
      });
       const chatMessage = await api.Position.get()
       return(chatMessage.json({ success: true, chatMessage}))
  }())

  app.listen(API_PORT, () => console.log(`LISTENING ON PORT ${API_PORT}`));
```

The data returned(res.data) is an object and you are trying to display within  tags. Note that you cannot display an object inside any html element.

For example, if your api response is :

```
data = {
name: "maxi",
place: "London",
}
```

you can render like

```
    <div>
          The name of the user is {this.state.data.name} and the city is {this.state.data.city}
   </div>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Im not even able to pass the data from nodejs to react  right now. it would be a good first step to get the info from nodejs to react for starters

Comment: Could be coz of body parser. Please try adding app.use(bodyParser.json());

Comment: could you specify in which file I should place this im super new to nodejs

Comment: I have edited the answer, let me know if you are able to proceed furthur :)

Comment: Its backend/server.js

Comment: what about the front end part? does that look correct?

Comment: Actually, the api response is an object { success: true, chatMessage}, whereas in the react component, you have initialized the state to be an array. Please check the return reponse and proceed :)

Comment: I have no idea if that part is correct: this is the actual response: https://www.bitmex.com/api/explorer/#!/Position/Position_get

Comment: Added a sample response in the actual question if that helps

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to display in the view. Try rendering this div to see the keys in the returned object ```<div>{Object.keys(this.state.data[0]).map((key) => {
        return <li>{key}</li>
      })}</div>```

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

I feel like this is not working: `componentDidMount() {
    console.log("fuck yes")
    this.getDataFromDb();
  }


  getDataFromDb = () => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3001/bitmex")
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(res => this.setState({ data: res.data }));
  };

Comment: just a clarification, with Postman are you able to hit the backend and get the desired response?

Comment: not sure what you mean by postman? 
But I do get the required info from the API, when the back end gets initialized.

Comment: just checked and no I cannot do that =(

Comment: Though I'm not happy directing you to something new at your earlier stage, but I believe you can make the best use of hooks in this case, https://medium.com/@cwlsn/how-to-fetch-data-with-react-hooks-in-a-minute-e0f9a15a44d6

Comment: Please check the example in https://blog.hellojs.org/fetching-api-data-with-react-js-460fe8bbf8f2  using fetch to make api calls. Note that "axios" has better approach of handling error and api calls than what "fetch" does, so do give a look at axios too. Happy coding!